# Cordova phone gap angular app not working on iOS 10.x versions

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I phone gapped an angular app using and trying to deploy to iPhone, iPad running (10.3 and 10.2) it is not working

I am using 
cordova 6.5.0

cordova-ios 4.3.1

Xcode - 8.3.2

If i deploy to iOS 9.3.5 app works fine perfectly.

If i deploy to 10.x version (10.2, 10.3) it doesn't work. 
After logging into the app, i get a modal dialog which i am not able to click. (Cannot navigate to app unless i click ok on this modal dialog). Add ngTouch module but it didn't work. Strangely it works once in 10 times. Is there something i am missing? Or there are issues with cordova with iOS 10.3. I am struggling with this issue for last couple of days. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

It works fine on android phone gapped version and also on web version (on safari)

Comment: Do you have a Content Security Policy meta tag in your index.html?

Comment: no.  Do i need one? I can programmatically invoke click on ok button from console. There is some invisible layer on top of the web view which is preventing to click on any buttons or menus on the page.

Comment: set the context-security-policy don't see any change

Comment: No, there is a problem affecting iOS 10 but only happens when the CSP is not correctly configured, if you don't have it then that's not the problem.

Comment: i made sure the z-index on the modal dialog is the highest one, still no luck. Surprising is it works sometimes like 5% of the time.

Comment: have u tried deploying to other targets besides IOS?